# Does this represent decoupling and correct use of interface

Tags: c#, interface, decoupling

I have written a short program to test my understanding of interfaces and decoupling. Could you tell me if my idea is correct. As I understand it, abstract methods of an interface are useful to use when more than one class can implement the same method. Decoupling then allows classes not to depend on each other. So, the HonkHorn() method which is defined in the ICar interface is implemented by two classes. Each class then contains an additional method that could be used to do something specific to the class it's in. Do I have the correct understanding?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Constructor
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SportsCar SportsCar = new SportsCar();
        CheapCar CheapCar = new CheapCar();
        label1.Text = SportsCar.HonkHorn();
        label2.Text = CheapCar.HonkHorn();
    }


}

interface ICar
{
    string HonkHorn();

}

public class SportsCar : ICar
{
    public string HonkHorn()
    {
        return "Horn honked on Sports Car";
    }

    public void DetermineHighestSpeed()
    { 
        // Calculation to determine highest speed on a sports car
    }

}

public class CheapCar : ICar
{
    public string HonkHorn()
    {
        return "Horn honked on Cheap Car";
    }

    private void FindRustSpots()
    { 
        // Algorithm to find rust spots
    }
}
```

Comment: Rich notice that implementing `HonkHorn` method is already doing *specific to the class it's in*

Answer (score 0):

You have a correct use of interface. But your sample does not represent decoupling, even though it's a good start. What you have described with your sample code is polymorphism through interface.

The definition of coupling in a static typed language is when a implementation of one class is required to compile the other.

Your sample class Form1 could be made fully decoupled by using the ICar interfaces and dependency inversion principle. (http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod)

Comment: Does that answer your question? Elaborate or ask for more references.

Comment: Thank you for your help.